# Puppeteer avoid akamai detection

Tags: puppeteer, headless, akamai

I am trying to scrape a page protected by akamai. There used to be no problems but since a couple of days i am having some troubles.

To scrape the site i am using the latest version of puppeteer, with puppeteer extra and steath.

I have found out that it blockes me from the first connection, so the problem is caused by browser info.

I got the parameters tested on the following site to be nominal. https://bot.sannysoft.com/ still i am getting blocked. Any ideas?

I will upload the blocked .har file shortly.

Comment: Also, if anyone wants to work together on this. Leg me know!

Comment: What website are you trying to scrape?